# My Javascript CountDown() is not working

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

My Countdown is not working... its show just 10.. I am trying run countdown timer on a click, under H5 heading, it will replace Open by timer,Clear by Reserved and Transparent background by orange color. and when it comes to less than 1, it will change change back again to default. abc() is function for onClick...

```
function abc() {
  if (firstTimer = "Open") {

    firstHeading.innerHTML = "Reserved";
    firstT.style.backgroundColor = "#D27900";

    function countDown(secs, elem) {
      var element = document.getElementById(elem);
      element.innerHTML = secs;
      if (secs < 1) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = "Open";
        firstHeading.innerHTML = "Clear";
      }
      secs--;
      var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + secs + ',"' + elem + '")', 10000);
    }
    countDown(10, "firstTblImageTimer");
  }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to using `timer` before it's declared. Also, why clear a `timeout`? They're "self clearing".

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: I’m your if statement it’s `===` not `=`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: i was seeing a tutorial of Countdown timer. so he used ClearTimeout

Comment: Mike Tung. === is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a wrong approach to solve this timer thing, you want the timer to update every second, therefore your timer should be called every second.
To make things clear, try to make every function to have only **One** responsibility, for example to code below:

```
function countDown( secs , elem ) {
    var updateElem =  function(){
        if(secs <= 0){
            elem.innerHTML = "Open";
            firstHeading.innerHTML = "Clear";
        }
        else{
            elem.innerHTML = secs;
        }
    }

    var checkTimeout = function(){
        if(secs <= 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else{
            updateElem();
            secs--;
        }
    }

    var timer = setInterval( checkTimeout,1000);
}
```

Do notice that I didn't look up for the element inside my function, but I'll will find it outside and I could reuse this function with other elements, so in my main function I'll have something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("firstTblImageTimer");
countDown(10 , element);
```

Comment: you mean that This VAR ELEMENT and COUNDOWN function should be written outside of the function?

Comment: var element = document.getElementById("firstTblTimer");
countDown(10 , element);

function abc(){
 if(firstTimer ="Open"){
  
  firstHeading.innerHTML = "Reserved";
  firstT.style.backgroundColor="#D27900";

Comment: function countDown( secs , elem ) {
    var updateElem =  function(){
        if(secs <= 0){
            elem.innerHTML = "Open";
            firstHeading.innerHTML = "Clear";
        }
        else{
            elem.innerHTML = secs;
        }
    }

    var checkTimeout = function(){
        if(secs <= 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else{
            updateElem();
            secs--;
        }
    }

    var timer = setInterval( checkTimeout,1000);
}
 }}

Comment: still not working... but now its not even changing colors and heading... first it was changing

Comment: you can share online snippets. there are plenty options. maybe http://collabedit.com?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused about how `setTimeout` works, since you are setting timeout to your `countdown` function inside the `countdown` function itself, and you will have to wait 10 seconds for your `countdown` function to be executed each time.
If you are willing to print a countdown, I would suggest you to use `setInterval` instead. Here is a boiler plate for your solution

```js
var secs = 10;
var countdown = function() {
    
 if(secs < 1) {
  clearInterval(myVar);
                // Do something while still counting down
  console.log("Time out!");
 } else {
               // Do something when you reach to zero
  console.log(secs);
  secs--;
 }
}
var myVar = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

I recomend you to take a look at [Window clearInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) and [Window setTimeout() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) W3School pages so you can understand how they work and the differences between each other and tell which method suites your problem better.

Comment: what does console.log() do

Comment: Sorry mate, I dont mean to be rude, but will have to google it yourself this time.